# Session State not saving value until third attempt

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state

I am currently trying to learn how to use session state but I have run into a problem that I can't figure out. What I am trying to do is have a button that when I click it, it will increase the value of my variable by 1, but my problem is that the first three times I click it my int does not increase but on the fourth click it works as intended and increases.

This is my code.

```
private static int Clicks = 1;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // First page load?
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Session["Clicks"] = Clicks; //Clicks
    }

    Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["Clicks"]);
}

protected void btnCounter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //UserClick.BtnClicks++;
    Session["Clicks"] = Clicks++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at the [ASP.NET Page Lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) (see Postback Event Handling).

That `btnCounter` click event won't get fired until after the `Page_Load` event. You will probably have better results if you update the `Label` within your `Click` event.

```
protected void btnCounter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["Clicks"] = Clicks++;
    Label1.Text = Session["Clicks"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, because you are hard setting that variable to'1', every time you click the button, it will reset to 1. You probably want to replace it with getter and setter that checks of session variable exists and, if it does, sets the value to that.